# How can I hard code logon parameters in a Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that runs from within an MS SQL Server based application.  The application can run reports based off of this database just fine, but now I need to run a report that also has another datasource, an Access db.  When I run the report from the CR designer it works.  However, when I run it from within the application it fails with incorrect logon parameters.  I think the application uses its own logon parameters to run reports.  I'm not 100% sure of this though because it happens "under the hood" of the application.  Is there any way I can force the report to use a certain logon for the Access db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly standard practice when an application embeds crystal reports that every table will be looped through and the logon parameters set to those of the application's data source.

The way i have achieved what you are looking to do in the past is create a view (possibly in conjunction with a linked server) in your application's database then you point the report at this/these view(s).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!  I am working on what you suggested.  In the meantime I am just running the report in an external viewer.  Kind of inconvenient, but it works till I can get the view set up.